# Function to determine path from imported module output

Tags: snakemake

We have a project in which we combine multiple independent Snakemake workflows using `subworkflow`. Now I'm trying to convert the project to use `module` instead but I'm facing difficulties due to either lacking features or documentation.

Previsouly we could in the "parent" Snakefile include a subworkflow like this (from the [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#sub-workflows):

```
subworkflow otherworkflow:
    workdir:
        "../path/to/otherworkflow"
    snakefile:
        "../path/to/otherworkflow/Snakefile"
    configfile:
        "path/to/custom_configfile.yaml"

rule a:
    input:
        otherworkflow("test.txt")
    output: ...
    shell:  ...
```

and then e.g. indicate that files should be found in the `workdir` of the `otherworkflow`by specifying `otherworkflow(<output_file>)`.

Problem:
When using Snakemake `module` an equivalent options seems to be missing.

My current workaround:
I reference the output of the module via `rules.<...>.output`, e.g.:

Snakefile 1:

```
rule a:
    output: "some_file.txt"
    shell: ...
```

Snakefile 2:

```
module other_workflow:
    snakefile: "<path to Snakefile 1>
    workdir: "<some workdir path>"

use rule * from otherworkflow as other_*

rule b:
    input: rules.other_a.output[0]
    shell: ...
```

Which works to some extent but is not as nice to read as the previous syntax from `subworkflow`.

Also: if the `output` contains a wildcard, then this workaround does not work anymore. (`expand`-ing the wildcard e.g. `expand(rules.other_a.output[0], wildcard_name=<value>)` does not work; what does work is `format`-ing `rules.other_a.output[0].format(wildcard_name=<value>)`)

I cannot find a similar functionality when using a Snakemake `module` for resolving filenames relative a modules `workdir`.

Q: Is there any solution for indicating an output is from an imported snakemake module and constructing the output path from `workdir` as we had with `subworkflow`?